# Error when trying to restart or stop sendmail on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, sendmail

I made some changes on my sendmail.mc file on CentOS. After making the changes, I attempted restarting the sendmail and I got this error.

554 5.0.0 QueueDirectory (Q) option must be set

I then undid the changes I made and I was still getting the same error. Please what could the problem be?

Comment: This doesn't answer your specific question, but it's a good argument for keeping your configuration files under version control, using for example something like git + http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/etckeeper/. Because it's pretty likely that you missed undoing something, or maybe your sendmail.mc file was changed in between the last time someone generated sendmail.cf from it and your edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On CentOS 5.5, you'll want to look at `/etc/mail/sendmail.cf` and make sure that the following option is set:

```
# queue directory
O QueueDirectory=/var/spool/mqueue
```